# Understanding Django's Model Class

Tags: python, django, oop

I'm new to both Python and Django, and I'm trying to get a sense for how Django's Model Class (and classes in general) work.

If you create a new model:

```
from django.db import models   

class Book(models.Model): 
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now you can do things such as:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Book
>>> book = Book(title="a new book", author="bob")
>>> book.save()
>>> print book.title
a new book
```

Great, it works. But the way that the Book class inherits from the Model class is a bit confusing. It would appear that title and author act as instance variables, but looking at the class definition it would appear that they are static.

```
from django.db import models 

class Book(models.Model):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.title = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    self.author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    super(Book, self).__init__()
```

To me, that seems to be the more intuitive way to declare the class, but Django does not pick these schema changes up when I run a migration. I understand why this doesn't work, I'm just not sure I understand why the above method *does* work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django's model classes are not a good way to learn about classes in general.  Django's model class uses meta classes and descriptors to work (both are relatively large topics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really too complex to answer in a question here. The quick answer is, it's all done with metaclasses, but for the full explanation you should read Marty Alchin's book *Pro Django*.

The point is that you don't want `self.title`, for example, to be a field instance: you want it to be whatever the *value* of the title is. So, (simplifying quite a bit) when the model instance is constructed from the database, the metaclass goes through the class-level Field attributes, and for each one it sets an instance-level attribute to the value of the db column. On save, of course, it does the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

class in python and how model in django are defined is different. The definition of model in django just use the syntax of python as a descriptive language for field and database related informations, then django introspect the class for extract this informations. But for the rest it's a normal python class, you can define method etc ...